# Does SQL92's REPEATABLE-READ preclude Write Skew (A5B)?

Tags: isolation-level

## REPEATABLE READ

In [SQL92](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt)'s definition, `REPEATABLE READ` is defined by serveral conditions.

P1 ("Dirty read"):

> 1) P1 ("Dirty read"): SQL-transaction T1 modifies a row. SQL-transaction T2 then reads that row before T1 performs a COMMIT. If T1 then performs a ROLLBACK, T2 will have read a row that was never committed and that may thus be considered to have never existed.

P2 ("Non-repeatable read"):

> 2) P2 ("Non-repeatable read"): SQL-transaction T1 reads a row. SQL-transaction T2 then modifies or deletes that row and performs a COMMIT. If T1 then attempts to reread the row, it may receive the modified value or discover that the row has been deleted.

Atomicity and `no updates will be lost`:

> The four isolation levels guarantee that each SQL-transaction will be executed completely or not at all, and that no updates will be lost.

Table 9, which defined `REPEATABLE READ` must preclude P1 & P2:

> Table 9, "SQL-transaction isolation levels and the three phenomena" specifies the phenomena that are possible and not possible for a given isolation level.

So in SQL92's definition of `REPEATABLE READ`, it must preclude P1, P2, and support for atomicity, no update lost.

## A5B (Write Skew)

On the other side, A5B (Write Skew) is defined in [A Critique of ANSI SQL Isolation Levels](http://arxiv.org/pdf/cs/0701157.pdf):

> Suppose T1 reads x and y, which are consistent with C(), and then a T2 reads x and y, writes x,and commits. Then T1 writes y. If there were a constraint between x and y, it might be violated. In terms of histories:
>
> r1[x]...r2[y]...w1[y]...w2[x]...(c1 and c2 occur)
>
> (Write Skew)

## Is `REPEATABLE READ` preclude A5B (Write Skew) ?

In the later paper, it claims `REPEATABLE READ` will preclude A5B (Write Skew) in **Table 4. Isolation Types Characterized by Possible Anomalies Allowed.**, and I am not conviced.

Any thought?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *Does REPEATABLE READ preclude Write Skew?*

**Yes** - if you buy into the Critique's view that the ANSI definitions were based on locking behaviours, for example:

> **Remark 6.** The locking isolation levels of Table 2 and the phenomenological definitions of Table 3 are equivalent. Put another way, PO, PI, P2, and P3 are disguised redefinitions of Locking behavior.

From that viewpoint, the history:

```
r1[x]...r2[y]...w1[y]...w2[x]...(c1 and c2 occur)
```

...is prevented when long-duration read shared locks are taken, because `w1[y]` is blocked by the lock taken by `r2[y]`. Similarly, `w2[x]` would be blocked by the lock taken by `r1[x]`. Therefore, this history cannot arise.

**No** - if you literally interpret the ANSI definitions. These are widely seen to be incomplete, so this outcome is not really all that surprising.